# Reference a file that is generated by the same script

Tags: terraform, f5

Having a trouble referencing a json file that is to be generated by null-resource local-exec.

Here is the snippet of the resource creating the file:

```
resource "null_resource" "clusterDO" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "cat > DO_template.json <<EOL\n ${module.bigip.onboard_do}\nEOL"
  }
  depends_on = [module.bigip.onboard_do]
}
```

Here is the snippet of the definition causing the error:

```
resource "bigip_do" "do-example" {
    do_json = "${file("DO_template.json")}"
    timeout = 120
    depends_on = [module.bigip_module]
}
```

Here is a snippet of the error:

```
Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "DO_template.json"; this function works only with files that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file will be
│ created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource.
```

I understand from the error that I can't reference the filename as is, not sure how to make it work, can someone provide an operational example?

Attempted to create the filename as a triggers in the null_resource and then reference it, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Do you need to append the value only or there are other parts of the file as well? If the file has other parts too, would you mind adding that to the question as well?

Comment: do_json should receive only the file specified.
In fact if I comment out the the "bigip_do" resource section on the first terraform apply during which the file will be created, and then uncomment the section and perform additional terraform apply it's all working as expected.
I'm struggling with the initial reference where is the file doesn't exist before the first run...

Comment: Ok, but `${module.bigip.onboard_do}` this is the only thing that will be inside of the file?

Comment: ah, yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by using the `templatefile` built-in function [1] and `local_file` [2] instead:

```
resource "local_file" "do_template" {
  content  = jsonencode(templatefile("${path.module}/DO_template.json.tpl", {
    onboard_do = module.bigip.onboard_do
  }))
  filename = "${path.module}/DO_template.json"
}

resource "bigip_do" "do-example" {
    do_json = file("${path.module}/DO_template.json")
    timeout = 120
    depends_on = [local_file.do_template]
}
```

Then, you would need to slightly adjust the JSON template (now called `DO_template.json.tpl`):

```
${onboard_do}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file#schema

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue, still get the same error: "Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "terraform-aws-bigip-module/examples/bigip_aws_3nic_deploy/DO_template.json"; this function works only with files that are distributed as part of the
│ configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource."

Comment: Ok, so have you created the `DO_template.json.tpl` file? Does it exist at all?

Comment: yes, it exists.
I just want to make it extra clear, the error that I'm getting is received when terraform is gathering the information and calculating what it needs to build.
Based on the error it appears that I need to specify the content of the "do_json" as an attribute, but I'm not sure how to do that....

Comment: What about `path.root` instead of `path.module`?

Comment: this won't change that fact that the file doesn't exist before the initial run.

Comment: But you said it exists, in your previous comment.

Comment: .tpl exists, but the .json file that is being created by it donsn't.
Either way I figured out that I should use the same variable that I provide to generate the JSON file, to provide it to the do_json function as well.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, reuse the same variable (being used to generate the local json file) within do_json, as follows:

```
resource "bigip_do" "do-example" {
    do_json = "${module.bigip.onboard_do}"
    timeout = 120
    depends_on = [local_file.do_template]
}
```